# Change maven repository for jenkins branches

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3

I have 3 branches and twenty jobs in each branch.

I would like to make that each branch (as well as the jobs it contains) uses a different maven directory and not use the same one as the others, which is by default (% user_home% /. M2 / repository).

Maven have just one settings.xml so I can't do `<localRepository>{your-new-path}</localRepository>` because each branch is different...

thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve by using different local m2 repos for each branch?

Comment: First in Jenkins each Jobs should use it's own local cache and never use a cache of others or the System which makes those jobs not independent any more....

Answer (score 2):

just add to your maven command **-Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.repository**

so each build will have it's own cache.